# Cannot read property $ of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Calling this function on a g is generating a "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" error, on the line where I try to append inputs (marked // HERE). Try as I might I cannot find where something goes undefined. How do I fix this?

Note: It's supposed to create checkboxes with labels and stored functions.

Here's a jsfiddle with a little driver code. http://jsfiddle.net/hevans1/huxe8ros/13/

EDIT: Sorry, I just found an unrelated error. Updated the code.

```
function CheckBoxFilter() {
  var labels = [];
  var functions = [];

  var updateData;

  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function() {
      var g = d3.select(this).append("g");

      var checkboxes = g.selectAll("input")
        .data(labels)
        .enter()
        .append()   // HERE
        .attr("class", "checkbox")
        .attr("type", "checkbox")
        .property("checked", true)
        .text(function(d) {
          return " " + d.name;
        });

      updateData = function() {
        var update = checkboxes.data(data);

        update.exit()
          .remove();

        update.enter()
          .append("input")
          .merge(update)
          .attr("class", "checkbox")
          .attr("type", "checkbox")
          .text(function(d) {
            return " " + d.name;
          });
      };
    });
  }

    chart.data = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return labels;
            labels = [];
        functions = [];

        var len = value.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
            labels.push(value[i].name);
            functions.push(value[i].func);
        }

        if (typeof updateData == "function") updateData();
            return chart;
        };

  return chart;
};
```

Sample data.

```
var age = [{
  name: "0-5",
  func: function(datum, checked) {
    return datum.age == "0-5" && checked == true;
  }
}, {
  name: "6-10",
  func: function(datum, checked) {
    return datum.age == "6-10" && checked == true;
  }
}, {
  name: "11-15",
  func: function(datum, checked) {
    return datum.age == "11-15" && checked == true;
  }
}, {
  name: "16-20",
  func: function(datum, checked) {
    return datum.age == "16-20" && checked == true;
  }
}, {
  name: "21-25",
  func: function(datum, checked) {
    return datum.age == "21-25" && checked == true;
  }
}, {
  name: "26-30",
  func: function(datum, checked) {
    return datum.age == "26-30" && checked == true;
  }
}, {
  name: "30+",
  func: function(datum, checked) {
    return datum.age == "31+" && checked == true;
  }
}, ];
```

Driver code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

        var age_filter = CheckBoxFilter().data(age);
        svg.call(age_filter);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that goes along with this script?

Comment: There is the HTML.

Comment: You are not passing any argument to `.append()`. You need to tell it **what** to append: `.append("input")`. https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#append

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I discovered that shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.append()` requires a CSS selector as an argument. In this case, one must tell it to append inputs: `.append("input")`.